# How to prevent button highlight

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistoryboard

I have a project with 2 buttons on my storyboard, I can click both at the same time, but only one triggers.

Is it possible for the second one to not get highlighted unless the first is pressed prior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set both buttons' exclusiveTouch property as true.

When exclusiveTouch property is set to true, you won't be able to touch both of them at the same time.

```
@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    button1.exclusiveTouch = true
    button2.exclusiveTouch = true
}
```

Comment: I hate to ask, But where can I find exclusive touch? Or do I need to do it in the  VIew Controller? I am coding in swift.

Comment: You need to do it in the view controller.

Comment: Developer.Apple says I am suppose to declare it with "var exclusiveTouch: Bool". But it's not working because "exclusiveTouch" is not a variable..

Comment: I edited my answer. After you connected your buttons as outlets, in viewDidLoad()  set their exclusive touch property as true.